# python web scrape with incremented id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Attempting to scrape a page that list data (table) per student (tr) and its data (td).

Each student listed in a tr has its own unique id tag that increments by 1 for each student.

Example: 1234-1, 1234-2, 1234-3 etc..

I have tried to add to the id by incrementing count variable by 1. Also the output only provides the first td and not all of the td's.

Im new to python and also webscraping and not sure why this is not working. Any help would be much appreciated

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = '' # Has been left blank for a reason
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

count = 1

print ('-' * 30)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('tr', attrs={'id': '1234-' + str(count)})

list_of_cells = []

while True:
    for cell in table.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('\xa0', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_cells.append(list_of_cells)

    student_name = list_of_cells[0]
    agent_id = list_of_cells[3].replace('-', '')

    total_hrs = list_of_cells[14]
    total_inc = list_of_cells[15]

    count += 1

    print (student_name, "| ", total_hrs, " ", total_inc)
else:
    print('Done')
```

Example of tr in table..

```
<tr height="17" id="1234-1" style="height:12.75pt;display:none">
  <td class="xl243045" height="17" style="height:12.75pt;border-top:none">
    <a href="48701">Student Name</a>
  </td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
  <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none">stuff</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautiful soup lets you select by regular expressions.  So you could do something this:

```
 import re

 # if you copy and paste this be wary of the "-" it doesn't appear to be a standard "-" on a US keyboard.  Make it match whatever is in the html
 students = soup.find_all("tr",id=re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d+'))
 for student in students:
    cells = student.find_all("td")
    student_name = cells[0].find('a').text
    total_hrs = cells[14].text
    print("{0}|{1}".format(student_name, total_hrs))
```

But I'm guessing your table is probably just filled with rows of students.  If it is then this may make more sense and be easier to follow:

```
#access the actual table holding the rows not the row itself -- notice the parent
table = soup.find('tr', attrs={'id': '1234-1'}).parent

# iterate over each of the rows (students)
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    student_name = cells[0].find('a').text
    total_hrs = cells[14].text
    print("{0}|{1}".format(student_name, total_hrs))
```

BTW, relying on the student id being in the table may not be the best idea. 
 Students typically change.  It's likely a much better idea to find something that identifies the table holding the students rather than relying on a particular student id to be in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The line `table = soup.find('tr', attrs={'id': '1234-' + str(count)})` needs to be within the loop where you increase `count`.

```
count = 1

print ('-' * 30)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

list_of_cells = []

while True:
    table = soup.find('tr', attrs={'id': '1234-' + str(count)})
    for cell in table.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('\xa0', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_cells.append(list_of_cells)

    student_name = list_of_cells[0]
    agent_id = list_of_cells[3].replace('-', '')

    total_hrs = list_of_cells[14]
    total_inc = list_of_cells[15]

    count += 1

    print (student_name, "| ", total_hrs, " ", total_inc)
else:
    print('Done')
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. This stopped the infinite loop that it was going to. But seems that the plus 1 increment is not working. Only providing the first students information.